# How to place Black rectangle in the Image

Tags: ios, xcode

I have path of the png file (Image). I would like to create new Image in the same folder where in the center of this Image will be Black rectangle with dimensions 300x100. Then I need to get the path of new created Image.

Can someone, please, help me with this issue?

[image]
I was playing with this code:

```
- (void) grayscale:(UIImage*) image {
    CGContextRef ctx;
    CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    NSUInteger height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *rawData = malloc(height * width * 4);
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger bytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * width;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData, width, height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    // Now your rawData contains the image data in the RGBA8888 pixel format.
    NSUInteger byteIndex = (bytesPerRow * 0) + 0 * bytesPerPixel;
    for (int ii = 0 ; ii < width * height ; ++ii)
    {
        // Get color values to construct a UIColor
        CGFloat red   = (rawData[byteIndex]     * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat green = (rawData[byteIndex + 1] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat blue  = (rawData[byteIndex + 2] * 1.0) / 255.0;
        CGFloat alpha = (rawData[byteIndex + 3] * 1.0) / 255.0;

        rawData[byteIndex] = (char) (red);
        rawData[byteIndex+1] = (char) (green);
        rawData[byteIndex+2] = (char) (blue);

        byteIndex += 4;
    }

    ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(rawData,
                                CGImageGetWidth( imageRef ),
                                CGImageGetHeight( imageRef ),
                                8,
                                CGImageGetBytesPerRow( imageRef ),
                                CGImageGetColorSpace( imageRef ),
                                kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast );

    imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage (ctx);
    UIImage* rawImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    CGContextRelease(ctx);

    self.workingImage = rawImage;
    [self.imageView setImage:self.workingImage];

    free(rawData);

}
```

But I didn't successed.

Comment: could you please share the already attempted code ?

Comment: Can you pleas give sample image to us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can draw image with another black layer on it. See below my code which will satisfy your requirement:

**Note: Please add image "testImage.png" into your code then execute below code.**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize strTemp3;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self testImageWrite];
    [self addNewImageFromPath];    
}

- (UIImage *)imageToDraw
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(300, 100), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    UIImage *natureImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImage"];
    [natureImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 100)];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect rectangle = CGRectMake(75, 25, 150, 50);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rectangle);

    UIImage *resultingImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return resultingImage;
}

- (NSString *)filePath
{
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.png"];
}

- (void)testImageWrite
{
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation([self imageToDraw]);
    NSError *writeError = nil;
    BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:[self filePath] options:0 error:&writeError];
    if (!success || writeError != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error Writing: %@",writeError.description);
    }
}

-(void)addNewImageFromPath{
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 100)];
    imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self filePath]];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];    
}
```

**Output:**

**Actual Image:** 
[image]

**New Image:**
[image]